# Angular Directives and Routing

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-routing

I have an Angular app consisting of an HTML page, a view being routed to that page, and a template for a directive that I want to add to the view being routed.

The index.html page displays the view using ngRoute fine. I am trying to use angular charts withing the view that is being routed, but I can't get the chart to show up. The code for the html page being routed is:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
    ...
    </head>
    <body>
        ---Some Code----
        <div create-chart></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The "create-chart" element refers to the directive which creates a chart in a separate html template.

The code for constructing the directive is:

```
var app = angular.module('penny', ['ngRoute', 'pennyControllers']);
app.config(['$routeProvider', ...

var chart = angular.module('chart', ['chart.js']);
  app.directive('createChart', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: '../chart/chart.html'
    };
  });
```

Does anyone know why the chart won't display?

Comment: Did you check your console?

Answer (score 1):

"A" is for attribute, "E" is for element. Since you are calling the directive from an attribute so use the following:

```
restrict: 'A'
```

Comment: This seems to work but nothing shows up in the div. There is clearly an outline of where the chart should be but the chart doesn't show up. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you please create and share a fiddle with your existing code, so it will be easier to make this working.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have put  restrict: 'E'

It's maybe not the reason but  'E' is for element.

With this you should used

```
<create-chart></create-chart>
```

First of all try restrict: 'A' to used `<div create-chart></div>`